# ActiveRecord join through two associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord

How do I get an ActiveRecord collection with all the unique `Jobs` that exist for a particular `User` given that there are two possible associations?

```
class User
 has_many :assignments
 has_many :jobs, through: assignments
 has_many :events
 has_many :jobs_via_events, through: :events, source: :jobs
end
```

```
class Assignment
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :job
end
```

```
class Event
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :job
end
```

```
class Job
 has_many :assignments
 has_many :events
end
```

The best I could come up with so far is using multiple joins, but it isn't coming back with correct results:

```
Job.joins("INNER JOIN assignments a ON jobs.id = a.job_id").joins("INNER JOIN events e ON jobs.id = e.job_id").where("a.user_id = ? OR e.user_id = ?", userid, userid)
```

Any advice?

Comment: You have a simple typo in your code: at the end you write `.where("a.job_id = ? OR e.job_id = ?", userid, userid)` and that should of course be `.where("a.user_id = ? OR e.user_id = ?", userid, userid)`. But not sure the query will work, when using two inner joins?

Comment: Ah good catch, but that was just a typo in retyping it here. I'll update my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to collect all job-ids first and then fetch all jobs for those ids.

We first ask for an array of all job-ids for a user:

```
event_job_ids = Event.where(user_id: user).select(:job_id).map(&:job_id) 
assignment_job_ids = Assignment.where(user_id: user).select(:job_id).map(&:job_id) 
all_job_ids = (event_job_ids + assignment_job_ids).uniq
```

note that, depending on the rails version you use, it is better to replace the `select(:job_id).map(&:job_id)` by a `.pluck(:job_id)` (which should be more efficient, but the `select.map`

Getting the jobs for the assembled ids is then straightforward:

```
 jobs = Job.where(id: all_job_ids)
```

This is the naive approach, how can we approve upon this? 
If I would write a query I would write something like the following

```
 select * from jobs 
 where id in (
   select job_id from assignments where user_id=#{user_id}
   union
   select job_id from events where user_id=#{user_id}
 )
```

so how do we convert this to a scope?

```
 class User

   def all_jobs 
     sql = <<-SQL
       select * from jobs 
       where id in (
         select job_id from assignments where user_id=#{self.id}
         union
         select job_id from events where user_id=#{self.id}
       )
     SQL  
     Job.find_by_sql(sql)
   end
```

Of course this is untested code, but this should get you started?